# Oracle 11.2 installation question

Tags: oracle, installation, upgrade

I have upgraded from Oracle 11.1 to 11.2 - but I can't see the new version...

When I type: `Select * from v$version` in pl/sql developer, I still see the old version

What can be the problem?

Comment: What exactly does v$version say?

Comment: he asked what **exact value** you get from that system view.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the [DBA SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site instead.  I can migrate it for you if you like.

Answer (score 1):

How did you upgrade?
Did you upgrade in place or out of place?
Did you configure the correct ORACLE_HOME for your database before the upgrade?
what does `select * from dba_registry;` tell you?

a little more info about the procedure and platform might help helping you.

If you don't know about Oracle upgrade process, running DBUA might be the smartest, if you have no DBA at hand. An Oracle Database upgrades constists of 2 steps

1. backup the database
2. create a new ORACLE_HOME with the
   new software - an out of place
   upgrade (or upgrade the ORACLE_HOME).
3. start the database using the new
   software in upgrade mode and adjust
   the internal database to the
   upgraded internal structures.
4. take a backup

DBUA helps you with this.

Comment: it gives me a table with all stuff. all the version are 11.1.0.6.0

Comment: In that case, assuming that your software is 11.2, you just started the database and did not upgrade it. You need to run some scripts to internally upgrade the structures to 11.2. Easiest to run is dbua - the DataBase Upgrade Assistant and perform the upgrade using that tool.

Comment: BTW: this <http://dba.stackexchange.com> might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The version is managed by the configuration file, once you upgraded 
you need to change the compatible parameter of the database's config
file so that oracle can start using the new features.

This can be done before the upgrade but it depends on what you want/need.

One way to upgrade a database is:

1. Install the target binaries
2. Run the preupgrade tool and follow the instructions
3. Copy the spfile from your source database ($ORACLE_HOME/dbs/spfile.ora) to the target Oracle home
4. Shutdown your database and change the $ORACLE_HOME to point to the target binaries
5. Start the database in upgrade mode
6. Follow the corresponding upgrade procedure of the version you are upgrading to
7. Start up the database in normal mode (if you have not run the utlrp do so to recompile the objects in the database)
8. If you want to make use of the new features you need to change the compatible parameter to the new version, be careful, this can't be undone and you will not be able to downgrade the database, Once you changed it you will have access to all the new features of the new version,
   I recommend you to create a pfile from your spfile and make the change there.
   Another option is to issue:

   alter system set compatible='new_version_4_dots' scope=spfile;

[Oracle upgrade documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/intro.htm#UPGRD001)